# Get Javascript variable from inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am brand new at coding and am playing with google maps. I have my map set up un the html window and I have a carousel of different poi's, which I have hard coded into the map. I want the poi marker to change based on which location is visible in the carousel. I have been able to retrieve the active carousel item(this.item), but can't get the variable out of this function. I appreciate any help.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
         this.item =  $('#this-carousel-id .carousel-inner .item.active').attr("data-id");

        markerCurrentPosition = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: pos,
            icon: currentPositionIcon,
        });
        map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });

    // watch for user's current position
    watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(updateUserPosition);

} else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
}
```

Comment: You want to just return `item`?

Comment: when I get the item I am going to bind it to different icons based on its value

Comment: console.log(this.item) inside the function gives a value of 1. From outside the function the value is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.item` is not a variable.  `this` is an object, and `item` is a key for a property in the object.  When you use the syntax:

```
this.item = something;
```

You are assigning a `key:value` pair (property) into the `this` object with a value of `something`.

If you viewed the object as a string it would look like this:

```
{"item":"something"}
```

To have a value available outside of a function, you could create a global object, and put the value inside of the global object.

```
var objGlobalForValues = {}; //Create a global object available globally

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
         .... Deleted to minimize code
         var myInfo =  $('#this-carousel-id .carousel-inner .item.active').attr("data-id");

        objGlobalForValues['myPropertyName'] = myInfo;

        .... Deleted to minimize code

}
```

See this documentation for info on JavaScript objects:

[Working With Objects - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: I was following http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS.html thinking "this" made it a public variable. Thank your help and the link.

Answer (score 0):

To get the variable out of the function, you have to affect the variable outside of the scope of the function... an example is this:

```
var t = {};

function test() {
   t["out"] = 1;
}

function test2() {
   console.log(t["out"]);
}


test2();
test();
test2();
```

The function `test` affect the variable inside the object `t`. Then the function `test2` can read what is stored inside `out`. In your case, the variable can be stored somewhere else that is accessible by other functions. The easiest way to achieve that is to store variables in the `window` variable. But it is highly recommended to not do so as it can be overridden by any other function/script.

As you're new to javascript, you should read a bit more about asynchronous functions.

Comment: I see what you're saying about asynchronous functions. Getting the variable does me no good without a callback and such. I think I bit off a bit more than I can chew here. Thank you for your help.